# Socket io v2 to v3 upgrade default namespace not connected

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am in the process of upgrading from socket io v2 to v3. Unfortunately I have the problem that the migration guide states: `No more implicit connection to the default namespace` which was used extensively so all socket io clients go through the session middleware.Did someone find a replacement.

It works if I also put the middleware with

```
io.of('/my-namespace').use(middleware())
```

but isn't quite an elegant solution as the list would grow with more namespaces.